# Selecting range based on specific text then fill with text

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to write a code where I want to look select range from Start to End in column A then fill the selected range in Column B with '1'. But my code only fill up bottom parts and missed out top parts. Refer to this photo. How do i make sure it go through every row and when it encounter Start, it will look for nearest End and fill up column B?

[image: Table]

```
Sub Select()
 Dim LastRowA As Long, i As Long
 Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRowA
            findrow = Range("A:A").Find("Start", Range("A1")).Row
            findrow2 = Range("A:A").Find("End", Range("A" & findrow)).Row
            Range("A" & findrow & ":A" & findrow2).Offset(0, 1).Value = "1"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find Start, loop through until it finds End. Tested and working as requested.

```
Sub Select()
 Dim LastRowA, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRowA
            If .Cells(i, 1) = "Start" Then
                Do Until .Cells(i, 1) = "End"
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value = 1
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Find is a precarious beast to use in VBA. It would be far simpler to just loop through the cells, keeping track of whether or not you're between Start and End:

```
Sub Select()
    Dim LastRowA As Long, i As Long, b As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRowA
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Start" Then
                b = True
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = 1
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 1).Value = "End" Then
                b = False
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = 1
            ElseIf b Then
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i tested the code and it works but i dont understand how `b=True/False' works and the range between Start and End was selected in this code. Do you mind to explain on it? Thanks!!!

Comment: A Boolean variable stores only True or False values. Here, I'm using True to indicate when i is a row number between Start and End. When we encounter Start it is set to True and when we encounter End it is set to False. For any other row that isn't Start or End, the code looks at the value of b to determine whether it is between Start and End. If it is between Start and End, b will be true and the last condition will pass, setting a 1. If it is not between Start and End, b will be false and the last condition will fail, so nothing is set on those rows.

Comment: thanks for detail explanation. Never thought Boolean True/False can be used this way!! Thanks!!